# Importing parent project directory from tests folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a suite of tests and it's in the project structured like this:

```
source/
    app/
    tests/
```

What would be the best way to make sure that the `tests` import everything in the `app`? Currently I'm putting the following three lines at the top of my tests initialization, but it seems like others have found out a more elegant way to do this but I'm not sure how:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir, os.pardir)))
from app.api import *
```

Comment: 2nd and 3rd line are not really related. you need 2nd line because you want to execute your tests from current directory. instead if you execute them from `source` directory, you will not need this line (unless `source` is not base and not added in path either). there is no work around for 3rd line as python don't have auto loading. at max you can add this in some other module and import that module instead.

Comment: What is your test runner? Are you installing the app in "editable" mode for testing/development?

Comment: @wim could you please clarify what you mean by 'editable' mode?

Comment: It means installing your app with `pip install --editable .`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `setup.py` is what you want?

You could package your app as a python module.

Here is the story. Firstly create a `setup.py` in your project, check [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py). And then install your project using develop mode.

```sh
python setup.py develop
```

After that, you could use the module without adding the directory into `sys.path`, as this module is installed under your python path.

```py
from app.api import *
```

With the `develop` option, you could debug this module.